# How to Remove Duplicate values in array in c#

Tags: arrays

```
  int[] a = new int[] { 10, 20, 10, 30, 40, 20, 50, 60 };
        int[] c = new int[10];
        int count = 0;
        int chk = 0;
        int temp;
        bool b=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {    chk = 0;
            if (a[i] != 0)
            {
              for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (a[i] == a[j])
                    {
                        chk++;
                    }

                }            
            }
            if (chk == 1)
            {
                c[count] = a[i];
                count++;
            }       
        }
        foreach (var x in c)
        {
            if(x!=0)
            {
            Response.Write(x);
                }}
```

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dictionary:

```
var dicArray = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

insert all value of array to Dictionary, like:

```
foreach of array:
dicArray[a[i]] = a[i];
```

then take all value of dicArray to new array (int).

Dictionary don't inser double key, this way key X insert just once.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ.

```
int[] a = { 10, 20, 10, 30, 40, 20, 50, 60 };
int[] c = a.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HashSet for keeping unique values!

```
int[] a = new int[] { 10, 20, 10, 30, 40, 20, 50, 60 };
var b = new HashSet<int>(a);    //HashSet of your values
var c = b.ToArray();            //Array from hashset
```